# android - can't write in added AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a app in android where I have a **AutoCompleteTextView** and when a **button** is clicked -> I am adding a new AutoCompleteTextView to the layout below the previous one.

for some reason, when I try to type in the added AutoCompleteTextView, I can't see the cursor and the text.
I tried to set the Text Color to RED - still can't see anything.

**My Code:**

addIngredient is called when the button is clicked

```
public void addIngredient(View view) {
    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView());
}

private TextView createNewTextView() {
    count++;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, mFirstTextView.getId());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, mFirstTextView.getId());
    params.topMargin = 50;
    params.height = findViewById(R.id.IngredientNumber1).getHeight();
    if (count == 2) {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mFirstTextView.getId());
    } else {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, count - 1);
    }
    AutoCompleteTextView newTextView = new AutoCompleteTextView(MainActivity.this);
    newTextView.setId(count);
    newTextView.setHint("this is new");
    newTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    newTextView.setThreshold(1);
    newTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    newTextView.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
    newTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return newTextView;
}
```

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Can you attach an image of your result display in the emulator or device? Because I am able to produce some text view with your code.

Comment: okay it was my bad.. some text color issue.. stupied :)